# error message on windows startup

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot, svchost

I'm using Windows XP. During startup I get the following screen.
Windows cannot find **C:\Program files\search extension\client.exe**. Make sure you types the name correctly, and then try again.To search for file, click the start button, and then click search
**svhost.exe** is also open in command prompt.
What should I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: [unasked for pop-up "Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Search Extensions\Client.exe'"](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/unasked-for-pop-up-windows-cannot-find-cprogram/bd5a1199-abe0-47b3-9e7d-b261b328a7e1)

Comment: "i unchecked it but it does not solved the problem." What is not fixed? Have you tried to delete the entry with Autoruns?

Answer (score 1):

Use msconfig.exe or [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and uncheck the startup entry for this client.exe.

[image]

Comment: msconfig.exe misspelled. please fix it.